# How to update a chart in Flutter (fl_chart)

Tags: flutter, dart, charts, fl-chart

I want to update the data of my chart, but it doesn't work. I used the chart I saw on a YouTube Video, which is using the fl_chart package. This is the whole code of the Youtube Video: https://github.com/JohannesMilke/fl_bar_chart_example. I think I have to use a setState somewhere, but I don't know where... I tried some options, but all failed, so I saw no other way than asking you. The weekChartDataGlobal is the varaiable which I want to be able to change, so my goal is to make the chart dynamic. I just putted you more or less the whole code into the question, because I don't know exactly what you need in order to answer my question. If you need more code please write me. Thanks in advance for helping me out with this big, big question.

```
class BarChartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BarChartWidgetState createState() => _BarChartWidgetState();
}

class _BarChartWidgetState extends State<BarChartWidget> {
  final double barWidth = 22;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BarChart(
      BarChartData(
        alignment: BarChartAlignment.center,
        maxY: 20,
        minY: 0,
        groupsSpace: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.05,
        barTouchData: BarTouchData(enabled: true),
        titlesData: FlTitlesData(
          bottomTitles: BarTitles.getTopBottomTitles(),
          leftTitles: BarTitles.getSideTitles(),
        ),
        gridData: FlGridData(
          checkToShowHorizontalLine: (value) => value % BarData.interval == 0,
          getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
            if (value == 0) {
              return FlLine(
                color: const Color(0xff363753),
                strokeWidth: 3,
              );
            } else {
              return FlLine(
                color: const Color(0xff2a2747),
                strokeWidth: 0.8,
              );
            }
          },
        ),
        barGroups: BarData.barData
            .map(
              (data) => BarChartGroupData(
                x: data.id,
                barRods: [
                  BarChartRodData(
                      y: data.y,
                      width: barWidth,
                      colors: [data.color],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                      )),
                ],
              ),
            )
            .toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

    class BarTitles {
      static SideTitles getTopBottomTitles() => SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            getTextStyles: (value) =>
                const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
            margin: 0,
            getTitles: (double id) => BarData.barData
                .firstWhere((element) => element.id == id.toInt())
                .name,
          );
    
      static SideTitles getSideTitles() => SideTitles(
            showTitles: true,
            getTextStyles: (value) =>
                const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
            rotateAngle: 90,
            interval: BarData.interval.toDouble(),
            margin: 0,
            reservedSize: 30,
            getTitles: (double value) => value == 0 ? '0' : '${value.toInt()}',
          );
    }
class BarData {
  static int interval = 5;

  static List<Data> barData = [
    Data(
      id: 0,
      name: 'Mon',
      y: weekChartDataGlobal[0]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      color: Color(0xff19bfff),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Tue',
      id: 1,
      y: weekChartDataGlobal[1]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      color: Color(0xffff4d94),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Wed',
      id: 2,
      y: weekChartDataGlobal[2]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      color: Color(0xff2bdb90),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Thu',
      id: 3,
      y: weekChartDataGlobal[3]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      color: Color(0xffffdd80),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Fri',
      id: 4,
      y: weekChartDataGlobal[4]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      color: Color(0xff2bdb90),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Sat',
      id: 5,
      y: weekChartDataGlobal[5]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      color: Color(0xffffdd80),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Sun',
      id: 6,
      y: weekChartDataGlobal[6]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      color: Color(0xffff4d94),
    ),
  ];
}

class Data {
  // for ordering in the graph
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final double y;
  final Color color;

  const Data({
    @required this.name,
    @required this.id,
    @required this.y,
    @required this.color,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the only way I got to update this chart is to put the chart inside a list variable, put this list inside the build method and replace the chart using a function everytime I want to update the chart. Let me try to explain it. Follow the steps in order to understand what i'm doing here and be patient. To test it right away just copy the code, delete my comments and run it. Don't forget to use pub get for fl_chart dependencies in pubspec.yaml and importing the library with the *import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';*

```
// STEP 1 - create the global variables - this is to adapt your code to this approach. 
//Put all these variables outside and above any function of your BarChartWidget class.

late BuildContext sameContext; //we will initialize this variable later, its the build's method context variable

late _BarChartWidgetState thisState; //we will initialize this variable later, its the class State variable, wich contains the setState method

double theChanges = 0; // this is a placeholder for your weekChartDataGlobal variable since i don't know what is this weekChartDataGlobal but i know its the info that will be displayed and updated in the Y axis of the chart so i replaced it with this double variable to ilustrate this approach

final double barWidth = 22; // your barWidth variable made global


// STEP 4 - here is the method to get a new chart. It's the exact same code of our theChart list 
//but once we throw the old BarChart widget away we need to get another and this new one will call all 
//its methods again and be updated with the new Y values from theChanges in new Data objects. 
//So this method just return the BarChart widget.
Widget getTheChart(){
  return BarChart(
    BarChartData(
      alignment: BarChartAlignment.center,
      maxY: 20,
      minY: 0,
      groupsSpace: MediaQuery.of(sameContext).size.width * 0.05,
      barTouchData: BarTouchData(enabled: true),
      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
        bottomTitles: BarTitles.getTopBottomTitles(),
        leftTitles: BarTitles.getSideTitles(),
      ),
      gridData: FlGridData(
        checkToShowHorizontalLine: (value) => value % BarData.interval == 0,
        getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
          if (value == 0) {
            return FlLine(
              color: const Color(0xff363753),
              strokeWidth: 3,
            );
          } else {
            return FlLine(
              color: const Color(0xff2a2747),
              strokeWidth: 0.8,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      barGroups: BarData.barData
          .map(
            (data) => BarChartGroupData(
          x: data.id,
          barRods: [
            BarChartRodData(
                y: data.y,
                width: barWidth,
                colors: [data.color],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ).toList(),
    ),
  );
}




// STEP 2 - Here i putted all the widgets of your page inside a list variable called theChart, 
//this is to make things easier to control, so we can update the BarChart widget easily. 
//In this list i'm putting your BarChart widget and a Button widget below it for you to be able to see 
//the chart being updated. I created this list too as a global variable. 
//Note that since this list is being declared outside the build method, we are using 
//sameContext variable instead of context and thisState.setState((){}) instead of setState((){}).
//As you can see in the list, the BarChart widget is placed at 0 and the Container holding the 
//MaterialButton is placed at 1.

List<Widget> theChart = <Widget>[
  BarChart(
    BarChartData(
      alignment: BarChartAlignment.center,
      maxY: 20,
      minY: 0,
      //sameContext variable being used here
      groupsSpace: MediaQuery.of(sameContext).size.width * 0.05,
      barTouchData: BarTouchData(enabled: true),
      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
        bottomTitles: BarTitles.getTopBottomTitles(),
        leftTitles: BarTitles.getSideTitles(),
      ),
      gridData: FlGridData(
        checkToShowHorizontalLine: (value) => value % BarData.interval == 0,
        getDrawingHorizontalLine: (value) {
          if (value == 0) {
            return FlLine(
              color: const Color(0xff363753),
              strokeWidth: 3,
            );
          } else {
            return FlLine(
              color: const Color(0xff2a2747),
              strokeWidth: 0.8,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
      barGroups: BarData.barData
          .map(
            (data) => BarChartGroupData(
          x: data.id,
          barRods: [
            BarChartRodData(
                y: data.y,
                width: barWidth,
                colors: [data.color],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                )),
          ],
        ),
      ).toList(),
    ),
  ),
  //this is the button widget, click to increase Y (theChanges variable) by 5,
//long press to decrease Y (theChanges variable)  by 5
  Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 0),
    child: MaterialButton(
      color: Colors.lightBlue,
      textColor: Colors.white,
      child: Text("Press me!"),
      onPressed: () {
//when you press the button we enter this method. Here we are outside the build method wich contains 
//the context and the state variables so we need to use our state variable to call the setState 
//method. This is the key point of the whole thing of updating the chart. We change the variable 
//holding the Y value in the chart, here i'm using my theChanges variable but in your code it's that weekChartDataGlobal. 
//Then we call the function BarData.updateData() (check step 3) to update the BarData static list variable wich contains the actual 
//objects holding the Y values in the chart, and then we REPLACE THE BarChart WIDGET. That's right we throw 
//the old widget away and replace it with a new one with the new values. Widgets atributes are final, we 
//can't change them once they're settled so we need to replace them, the sooner you accept it the sooner you'll understand all this.
        thisState.setState((){
          theChanges += 5;
          BarData.updateData();
          theChart.removeAt(0);
          theChart.insert(0, getTheChart()); // check step 4
        });
      },
      onLongPress: (){
        thisState.setState((){
          theChanges -= 5;
          BarData.updateData();
          theChart.removeAt(0);
          theChart.insert(0, getTheChart());
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
].toList();

class BarChartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BarChartWidgetState createState() => _BarChartWidgetState();
}

class _BarChartWidgetState extends State<BarChartWidget> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // at this method your page will actually be built, here is where all the action will happen 
//indeed so we
    sameContext = context; // initialize our global context variable
    thisState = this;  // initialize our global State variable

    //here we put theChart list variable inside a ListView and the ListView inside a container. 
//The build method will get each widget inside the list and place it in order
    return Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: theChart.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return theChart[index];
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BarTitles {
  static SideTitles getTopBottomTitles() => SideTitles(
    showTitles: true,
    getTextStyles: (value) =>
    const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
    margin: 0,
    getTitles: (double id) => BarData.barData
        .firstWhere((element) => element.id == id.toInt())
        .name,
  );

  static SideTitles getSideTitles() => SideTitles(
    showTitles: true,
    getTextStyles: (value) =>
    const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12),
    rotateAngle: 90,
    interval: BarData.interval.toDouble(),
    margin: 0,
    reservedSize: 30,
    getTitles: (double value) => value == 0 ? '0' : '${value.toInt()}',
  );
}

// STEP 3 here i replaced your weekChartDataGlobal with my theChanges variable to ilustrate the 
//update and created the updateData() method.
class BarData {
  static int interval = 5;

  static List<Data> barData = [
    Data(
      id: 0,
      name: 'Mon',
      //y: weekChartDataGlobal[0]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      y: theChanges,
      color: Color(0xff19bfff),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Tue',
      id: 1,
      //y: weekChartDataGlobal[1]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      y: theChanges,
      color: Color(0xffff4d94),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Wed',
      id: 2,
      //y: weekChartDataGlobal[2]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      y: theChanges,
      color: Color(0xff2bdb90),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Thu',
      id: 3,
      //y: weekChartDataGlobal[3]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      y: theChanges,
      color: Color(0xffffdd80),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Fri',
      id: 4,
      //y: weekChartDataGlobal[4]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      y: theChanges,
      color: Color(0xff2bdb90),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Sat',
      id: 5,
      //y: weekChartDataGlobal[5]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      y: theChanges,
      color: Color(0xffffdd80),
    ),
    Data(
      name: 'Sun',
      id: 6,
      //y: weekChartDataGlobal[6]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
      y: theChanges,
      color: Color(0xffff4d94),
    ),
  ];

//this is another key point. Note that here i'm just clearing the whole static list and filling it 
//again with the Data objects. I just copied the code above to create the static list and 
//pasted down there. Why? Widgets attributes are final, their Y parameter won't change even if 
//you update the theChanges variable so you need to throw them all away and place new ones 
//with the new value of theChanges variable.
  static void updateData(){
    barData.clear();
    barData = [
      Data(
        id: 0,
        name: 'Mon',
        //y: weekChartDataGlobal[0]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
        y: theChanges,
        color: Color(0xff19bfff),
      ),
      Data(
        name: 'Tue',
        id: 1,
        //y: weekChartDataGlobal[1]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
        y: theChanges,
        color: Color(0xffff4d94),
      ),
      Data(
        name: 'Wed',
        id: 2,
        //y: weekChartDataGlobal[2]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
        y: theChanges,
        color: Color(0xff2bdb90),
      ),
      Data(
        name: 'Thu',
        id: 3,
        //y: weekChartDataGlobal[3]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
        y: theChanges,
        color: Color(0xffffdd80),
      ),
      Data(
        name: 'Fri',
        id: 4,
        //y: weekChartDataGlobal[4]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
        y: theChanges,
        color: Color(0xff2bdb90),
      ),
      Data(
        name: 'Sat',
        id: 5,
        //y: weekChartDataGlobal[5]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
        y: theChanges,
        color: Color(0xffffdd80),
      ),
      Data(
        name: 'Sun',
        id: 6,
        //y: weekChartDataGlobal[6]['dayTime'].toDouble(),
        y: theChanges,
        color: Color(0xffff4d94),
      ),
    ];
  }
}

class Data {
  // for ordering in the graph
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final double y;
  final Color color;

  const Data({
    required this.name,
    required this.id,
    required this.y,
    required this.color,
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone doesn't want to do such a complex workaround, I simply added a `ValueKey` to my graph constructor. Then attached this to my selector widget, which changes the timeframe my graph is showing, e.g. day, month, week.

e.g.

`String _yourVariableThatChangesHere = "monthView";`

```
GTBarChart(
    key: ValueKey(_yourVariableThatChangesHere),
    data: ...
)
```

Then when your `_yourVariableThatChangesHere` changes, the graph gets rebuilt when you call `setState`.